# How to use CountDownLatch in a multithreading program

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm a beginner in Java and am trying to create a program where two "boats" race each other down the screen using multithreading. I got the threading part to work with two lines coming down the screen parallel to one another.

But I wanted the threads to start at the same time on command, so I found the CountDownLatch class. I really didn't understand it well, but I tried to use it still using a latch, and getting the threads to await() until I called `latch.countDown()`. This all worked fine too, but I wanted to know which thread finished first, so I used a timer and an `if` statement in the main method to determine which thread/"boat" was faster.

However my two problems were that a. for some reason, everything prints twice, as if it's doing the run() twice, and b. the if statement always goes straight to else, as in it doesn't think either of the recorded times are greater than the other. I have a feeling all of this is due to some mess up I made with the CountDownLatch, but I just don't have the experience to figure it out.

Main method:

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.*;

public class Regatta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q timed = new Q();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(0);
        Thread t1 = Thread.currentThread();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What team is rower 1 on?");
        String roweronename = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What team is rower 2 on?");
        String rowertwoname = scan.nextLine();

        Rower r1 = new Rower(latch, roweronename, timed);
        Team2 r2 = new Team2(latch, rowertwoname, timed);

        try {
            System.out.println("ATTENTION");
            t1.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("READY");
            t1.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("ROW!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(roweronename.toUpperCase() + "             " + rowertwoname.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
            new Thread(r1).start();
            new Thread(r2).start();
            latch.countDown();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error. Don't click out of the program.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There was another error");
        }
        try {
            r1.t.join();
            r2.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interruption error occurred");
        }
        double finalTimeOne = r1.finalTime;
        double finalTimeTwo = r2.finalTime;

        if (finalTimeOne < finalTimeTwo) {
            System.out.println(roweronename.toUpperCase() + " HAS WON THE RACE!");
        } else if (finalTimeTwo < finalTimeOne) {
            System.out.println(rowertwoname.toUpperCase() + " HAS WON THE RACE!");
        } else
            System.out.println("Nobody won");
    }
}
```

subclass with thread1:

```
package practice;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Rower implements Runnable {
    int meters = 2000;
    double startTime, endTime, finalTime;
    Thread t;
    String name;
    CountDownLatch latch;
    Q timed;
    public Rower(CountDownLatch latch, String name, Q timed) {
        this.timed=timed;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.name = name;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
        System.out.println();   
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
            double startTime = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("|");// each - is 10 meters
                Thread.sleep(100);
        }
            double endTime = System.nanoTime();
            double finalTime = endTime - startTime;
            timed.getTime(finalTime,name);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("GET OUT THE WAY!");
            System.out.println("race postponed to tommorow");
        }

    }

}
```

subclass with thread 2:

```
package practice;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Team2 implements Runnable {
    Q timed=new Q();
    int meters = 2000;
    double startTime,endTime,finalTime;
    Thread t;
    String name;
    CountDownLatch latch;
    public Team2(CountDownLatch latch,String name, Q timed) {
        this.timed=timed;
        this.latch=latch;
        this.name = name;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        t.start();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            latch.await();
            double startTime=System.nanoTime();

            for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
                int j=20-i;
                System.out.println("                  |");// each | is 10 meters
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            double endTime=System.nanoTime();
            double finalTime=endTime-startTime;

                timed.getTime(finalTime, name);


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("GET OUT THE WAY!");
            System.out.println("race postponed to tommorow");
        }

    }

}
```

class with synchronized method to get finishing times:

```
  package practice;    
   public class Q {
    double finalTime;
    String name;
    synchronized void getTime(double finalTime, String name){
        this.finalTime=finalTime;
        this.name=name;
        System.out.println("Time of team "+this.name+": "+this.finalTime);//prints twice?
        System.out.println("vinay");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Rower (and Team2) class constructors, you are initializing a brand new Thread, and starting it:

```
public Rower(CountDownLatch latch, String name, Q timed) {
    this.timed=timed;
    this.latch = latch;
    this.name = name;
    //vvvvvvvv THIS IS THE PROBLEM vvvvvvvv//
    t = new Thread(this, name);
    t.start();
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
    System.out.println();   
}
```

You do NOT need a Thread inside Rower (or Team2). The threads created in your Regatta class are sufficient to invoke the "run" method in Rower (and Team2)

```
// These are all you need to get the boats to race!
new Thread(r1).start();
new Thread(r2).start();
```

Also, as a side note: You DO NOT need the Team2 class at all... You should be able to race two different boats by initializing two Rower objects.

```
Rower r1 = new Rower(latch, roweronename, timed);
// Changed from Team2 to Rower
Rower r2 = new Rower(latch, rowertwoname, timed);
```

You would only need to have two different boat classes if the two boats had different functionality, like one was propelled different than another one (rowing vs sailing, vs motorboat, etc). In your case, they look essentially identical (almost copy-pasted).

Comment: OH MY GOD, THANK YOU! But about the second part, the reason for the other class was because I needed one of the threads to be printing several spaces away from the first thread. The first thread was printing "|" while the other was printing " ----------------------- |". If you could tell a better way to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.(the dashes are spaces)

Comment: There are a bazillion ways to print custom values like you are suggesting, but one way would be to send the desired value into a constructor argument, and store that in the class. `String rowereonetail = "|";` `Rower r1 = new Rower(latch, roweronename, timed, roweronetail);` Then update the Rower class constructor to take the tail parameter: `Rower(CountDownLatch latch, String name, Q timed, String tail) {` Set it locally: `this.tail = tail;` Then update the print method: `System.out.println(tail);`

Comment: Glad it's working for you! Feel free to accept this as the "correct answer"